# How can I open a puppeteer Page in an Electron BrowserWindow

Tags: javascript, electron

In ElectronJS, I can use the following to open a `BrowserWindow`:

```
let window = new BrowserWindow({ width: 600, height: 400 });
```

Additionally, I can use the following to launch a headful Chromium instance with Puppeteer:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch(
{
    headless: false
});
```

However, rather than open a new Chromium window (i.e. have Chromium launch in its own window), I would like to embed it directly into my app in a `BrowserWindow` (i.e. have Chromium launch inside of my app as if it is some kind of integrated browser).

I'm looking for something which is aesthetically identical to embedding a `BrowserView` into my `BrowserWindow` like this:

```
let view = new BrowserView();
window.addBrowserView(view);
view.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 400 });
```

However, I want to do this with a Puppeteer `Page`.

Comment: please show some code example. I have a hard time understanding your question.

Comment: you want to do this? https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4655

Comment: I have edited my post with some code. Please let me know if this is still too vague.

Comment: The issue you linked is someone wanting to use puppeteer to control Electron. Instead, I want to use Electron to show a Puppeteer `Page` (as seen in the second to last paragraph [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4655#issuecomment-519579145)).

Comment: So, check his code or use his project, I'd say.

Comment: The project he linked does not do what I am seeking; he just mentioned it as an afterthought in that comment. I am looking to embed a puppeteer `Page` into an Electron `BrowserWindow`. Instead, he is using puppeteer to control an Electron `BrowserWindow`.

Answer (score -2):

You can add another page into your window with the `newPage` function on the browser class.

and with the `pages` function you can destructure the pages and name them so you can play with them.

as following:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
await browser.newPage();
const [firstPage, secondPage] = await browser.pages();

// use both pages
firstPage.goto('www.google.com')
secondPage.goto('www.bing.com')
```

note: the `newPage` and the `pages` function is asynchronous so you'll need to wait for the result.

Comment: That is not using electron in any way.

Comment: I have no issues using Puppeteer; I am looking for a way to have this Chromium window render inside of my `BrowserWindow` rather than open in its own window.